# Unable to find error codes for aws-ivs-web-sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ivs

I'm using IVS Web Sdk v1.21.0 in Next.JS / React.JS framework.

I'm getting various error code & error messages from ivs instance.

```
const onErrorCallback = (err) => {
/.../
const { code, type, message } = err
/.../
}

ivsPlayerRef.addEventListener(IVSPlayer.PlayerEventType.ERROR, onErrorCallback)
```

I'm getting various different code/message which I'm unable to replicate or understand.
like: code -1, -3 & 4
message: 'No playable format', 'Failed to parse HLS master playlist invalid content type: application/octet-stream' & various others.

Can someone tell me where to find error code or error types

```
Below is the list for error code
1. Failed to execute 'addSourceBuffer' on 'MediaSource': The type provided ('video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42001e"') is unsupported.
2. Failed to execute 'addSourceBuffer' on 'MediaSource': The type provided ('video/mp4;codecs="mp4a.40.2"') is unsupported.
3. TypeError: t is undefined
4. DECODER_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED: audio decoder initialization failed
5. Unsupported source type
6. The MediaSource was closed upon opening
7. MediaSource.addSourceBuffer: Can't play type
8. t.headers is undefined
9. No playable format
10. PIPELINE_ERROR_DECODE
11. PIPELINE_ERROR_DECODE: video decoder reinitialization failed
12. PIPELINE_ERROR_NETWORK
13. AUDIO_RENDERER_ERROR: audio render error
14. Source create failed
15. TypeError: can't access property "indexOf", t is undefined
16. NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
```

Comment: were you able get any callback for error

Comment: @VickyKumar Yes, as I mentioned above... `onErrorCallback` is working prefectly fine.

Comment: I want to know different types of error thrown by IVS player